# Run Ansible task on SUSE machines only

Tags: ansible, suse

I want to execute my Ansible task only on a specific SUSE version. But this task gets executed for all Linux OS flavors. Which is not expected. Can someone help me with this? Why is the when condition not working? What I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
# Action 146: addlink ld-lsb.so.3->ld-2.11.1.so in /lib on sles11.x,12.x for lmutil in cct2000739233
  - name: Addlink ld-lsb.so.3->ld-2.11.1.so in /lib on sles11.x,12.x for lmutil
    shell: "ls ld-*.so|grep -v lsb|head -n 1"
    args:
      chdir: /lib
    register: ldso

  - stat:
      path: /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
    register: lib64_result

  - stat:
      path: /lib/ld-lsb.so.3
    register: lib_result

  - block:
      - file:
          src: "/lib/{{ ldso.stdout }}"
          dest: /lib/ld-lsb.so.3
          state: link
          force: true
      - file:
          src: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
          dest: /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
          state: link
          force: true
    when:
      # Check the OS level. Make sure it runs only on SLES-11 SP4,SLES-12SP0/1/2/3
      - ansible_distribution == 'Suse'
      - ansible_distribution_major_version == "11"
      - ansible_distribution_release == "4"
      - ansible_distribution_version == "11.4"

      - ansible_distribution == 'SLES'
      - ansible_distribution_major_version == "12"
      - ansible_distribution_release == "0" or "1" or "2" or "3"
      - ansible_distribution_version == "12.0" or "12.1" or "12.2" or "12.3"

      - not lib64_result.stat.exists|bool or not lib_result.stat.exists|bool
      - ldso.stdout != ''

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ldso.stdout }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot do `or` like that.  Has to be like this:

```
  - ansible_distribution_release == "0" or ansible_distribution_release == "1" or ansible_distribution_release == "2" or ansible_distribution_release == "3"
  - ansible_distribution_version == "12.0" or ansible_distribution_version == "12.1" or ansible_distribution_version == "12.2" or ansible_distribution_version == "12.3"
```

The way you have it, `ansible_distribution_release == "0" or "1"`,  `ansible_distribution_release == "0"` evaluates to `false`, that's fine, but then `"1"` evaluates to `true`.  `false or true` then evaluates to `true`.